# ZX Spectrum scroll waiting for user input problem

Tags: z80, zx-spectrum, c

I'm trying to compile a C program with z88dk for the ZX Spectrum. Using `printf()`, when the text hits the bottom line of the screen on line 24 the program stops executing until a key is pressed on the keyboard - but I need `printf()` to not lock up waiting for a key to be pressed.

The github page for z88dk states: 
"The screen scrolls when line 24 is "hit", the routine used is in the 48k ROM."
Is this what I need to disable? Is this scroll routine being fired, and is this what waits for user input before continuing?

In BASIC, the "scroll?" message can be disabled with `POKE 23692,n` and printing behaves normally. I have tried to call `zx_bpoke(23692, 255);` to try to disable the wait in C but this has no effect. How can I scroll without waiting for a keypress?

Is `23692` the right address to poke for the 48K ROM to disable the scroll key press routine?

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <z80.h>
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i); //<-- will pause here until key is pressed when bottom of the screen is hit
        //attempt to disable this in the scroll routine
        z80_bpoke(23692, 255); //<-- doesn't work?

    }
}
```

I compile with the command:

```
zcc +zx -vn -startup=1 -clib=new -create-app main.c -o out
```

After line 23, the Spectrum waits for a key to be pressed, even when POKING at address 23692. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems an older version of z88dk had a scrolling issue: https://www.z88dk.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9145

Answer (score 5):

One of the complications with z88dk is that there are two libraries: classic and newlib. These days, a lot of the code is shared but there are two separate implementations of stdio and console drivers. The comment about "ROM driver" is referring to how classic scrolls the screen: it just calls address 3582 in ROM3 by default.

However, the compile line mention, uses newlib, and the console driver for startup=1 isn't the ROM printer so won't respond to a poke 23692,255, but a custom terminal driver. The behaviour of the terminal is controlled by an ioctl call disabling the IOCTL_OTERM_PAUSE flag:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <z80.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main() {
    // Disable waiting for input when the screen is scrolled
    ioctl(1, IOCTL_OTERM_PAUSE, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);

    }
}
```

This information was taken from the following project issue: https://github.com/z88dk/z88dk/issues/682#issuecomment-379526038

Answer (score 1):

In ZX Spectrum basic, `POKE 23692,255` works fine, when done every line to be printed -- the scroll becomes effectively infinite and never requests "scroll?". Check that `printf()` code does not fiddle with the 23692 value and that `z80_bpoke(23692, 255);` really does what it is intended to do. Maybe `*((char *)23692)=0;` would work instead?

Comment: you mean `*((char *)23692)=255;` probably

Comment: actually there is no difference between 0 and 255, if set every printed line.